# How can i parse a string from post in my controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, parsing

i have a multi valued textarea with auto suggestions. Now, i am receiving a string with somehow array structured string in my controller. I want to insert this in my database with one by one. Something like, i want them to inserted in my database as one by one. I am having a problem how can i parse this type from my controller.

Here is my controller :

```
public function finish_checkup($patient_id,$queue_id,$checkup_id,$clinic_id) {
    $diagnosis = $this->input->post('tdiagnosis');
    var_dump($diagnosis);    
}
```

now when i `var_dump($diagnosis);` the value of this is :

```
string(30) "["Cobol","JavaScript","Scala"]"
```

now what i want is to parse this string one by one, so that i can insert this values to my database something like:

```
checkup_id   language
1             cobol
2             javascript
3             scala
```

Comment: use `explode(",",$diagnosis)`. It will return you an array

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR can you answer with that sir ? . below, on how to use or what would be the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the explode() function of php to split the string based on a character as

```
public function finish_checkup($patient_id,$queue_id,$checkup_id,$clinic_id) {
    $diagnosis = $this->input->post('tdiagnosis');
    $var=json_decode($diagnosis);
    var_dump($var);    
}
```

Comment: yes that is correct, you get an array, now you can use it

Comment: But the `[` and `]` is that supposed to be in the array? Edit and extra "

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR yes, then can i do like this? , i will get the length of that array and loop it with its length and insert into ? something like my id is auto increment?

Comment: Here now I have echoed the array for you. See the difference? https://3v4l.org/fLk02

Comment: yes use this `INSERT INTO table_name( checkup_id) VALUES ($diagnosis[0]),($diagnosis[1]),($diagnosis[2])`

Comment: @Andreas I think you have json encoded array in db, so i updated my answer please check now. Here is a working php fiddle for that `//phpfiddle.org/lite?code=<?php\n $diagnosis ='["Cobol","JavaScript","Scala"]';\nvar_dump($diagnosis);\n$var=json_decode($diagnosis);\necho "<pre>";print_r($var);\n //$diagnosis= explode(",",$diagnosis);\n //var_dump($diagnosis);\n?>\n`

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR It's not really json. It looks like json but isn't. See here what json should look like https://www.w3schools.com/js/showphp.asp?filename=demo_file the string in question does not have { } it has [ ] and does not have values to each item. I see that it works, but I would not use a function that is not intended to read this type of string. It may have unforseen consequences if the string looks slightly different. If the string in qustion was json it would look like this: https://3v4l.org/Bvo3C

Answer (score 2):

Regex

```
preg_match_all("/\"(\w+?)\"/", '"["Cobol","JavaScript","Scala"]"', $arr);


Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/R1nlh

Captures "words" in between ""

Comment: preg_match_all("/\"(\w+?)\"/", $tdiagnosis, $arr); can i use something like this?

Comment: @JcJohn do you need anything else?

Comment: why is it there are two outputs? .. i only need the second output, and how can i use this if i only need the second output which is i only need the output [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Cobol"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "JavaScript"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Scala"
  }

Comment: i only need the output [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Cobol"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "JavaScript"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Scala"
  }

Comment: @JcJohn regex always create two arrays. One is the full match and the other is what you want to capture. The full match is good in my opinion because with that you can debug the code. But if you want to remove the full match and only keep the capture you can use this: https://3v4l.org/LHV3g

Comment: But I thought you used the other answer by raushan?